# Howto write UUID raw 16 bytes to CSV in golang?

Tags: csv, go, uuid

I have following code, which try save UUID raw 16 bytes (with 0x0A inside) to CSV format

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "github.com/satori/go.uuid"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    u, err := uuid.FromString("e1393c62-877a-4adc-8ffb-f1bf0a337c5f")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    csv_file, err := os.OpenFile("csv_wtf.csv", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    s := string(u.Bytes())
    log.Printf("len(s)=%d",len(s))
    csv_writer := csv.NewWriter(csv_file)
    csv_writer.UseCRLF = false
    csv_writer.Write([]string{s})
    csv_writer.Flush()
    finfo, err := csv_file.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("size csv_wtf.csv = %d", finfo.Size())
    csv_file.Close()
}
```

this code output data to csv with add extra bytes

```
2017/04/16 12:37:14 len(s)=16
2017/04/16 12:37:14 size csv_wtf.csv = 29
```

why encoding/csv add extra bytes when follow my string over range (see https://golang.org/src/encoding/csv/writer.go#L38, https://golang.org/src/encoding/csv/writer.go#L50 and https://golang.org/src/encoding/csv/writer.go#L76)?

could somebody help me find CSV package who don't do it strange conversion ??

Comment: What does the data look like in the CSV file, and what does `s` look like. By just looking at the lengths it's hard to see what happens.

Comment: i need insert FixedString(16) optimized UUID storage into https://github.com/yandex/clickhouse database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because CSV format is not suitable for storing raw binary data, which is unlikely to be a valid utf-8 sequence.

What happens is that when `csv_writer.Write` [iterates a string with `range` loop](https://golang.org/src/encoding/csv/writer.go#L60), every time it encounters an invalid utf-8 sequence, the rune `r1` gets equal to 65533, which is encoded as 3 bytes: `0xef, 0xbf, 0xbd`.

Illustrative example:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    invalidString := string([]byte{0xff, 0xfe, 0xfd})
    var b bytes.Buffer
    for _, r := range invalidString {
        fmt.Printf("current rune: %v\n", r)
        b.WriteRune(r)
    }

    fmt.Printf("total data: %v\n", b.Bytes())
}
```

The output is:

```
current rune: 65533
current rune: 65533
current rune: 65533
total data: [239 191 189 239 191 189 239 191 189]
```

So you should either abandon CSV in favour of some other format (suitable for storing binary data), or store UUIDs in their string form.